# Sending precise datetime to SqlDataSource as parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server

I want to add a .Net DateTime as a parameter to a SqlDataSource. I know how to add the parameter, but I need to add the DateTime as precisely as I possibly can. It needs to be very precise, since some tables use datetime columns as keys, and if the datetime sent through is not precise enough, joins will not work correctly.

The old way (without SqlDataSource) is something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "PosT2sNwu.RPT_GetFundTransactions";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FromDate", fromDate));
```

It seems that the parameters for SqlDataSource only takes strings.

So the question is: How do I format the string (generated from the .Net DateTime) so that it ends up in the stored procedure as precisely (up to the milli, or even microsecond) as possible?

Comment: 1.[Be careful using a datetime column as part of a primary key](http://weblogs.asp.net/bkcarroll/archive/2004/05/13/131329.aspx) 2.[No DateTime primary keys, please](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/abouttn/flash/tips/tips_031604.mspx).

Comment: Try out fromDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss fffffffzz"),

Comment: Formatting the dates is the root of all evil.

Comment: Yes. I cannot understand why microsoft decised to take a step backwards, only allow you to set the parameter as a string. Why not allow me to set a DateTime object directly?

Comment: fromDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss fffffffzz") does not work, however, fromDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss fffffff") (without the zz) seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use overloaded `SqlParameter` constructor that is using `SqlDbType` as parameter

```
SqlParameter(String, SqlDbType, Int32) 
SqlParameter(String, SqlDbType, Int32, String)
```

Then use SqlDbType.DateTime described on MSDN page as "Date and time data ranging in value from January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999 to an accuracy of 3.33 milliseconds".

Comment: I don't think really answers the question

Comment: Bertus has to decide. And according to this forum thread http://www.progtown.com/topic7961-accuracy-loss-at-usage-sqlparameter-in-sqlclient.html there's an accuracy loss: "Values are rounded to increments of .003, or .007 seconds, as shown in the table."

Comment: I will mark this up again, simply for introducing the .003 and .007 accuracy info into the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Is this any use?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx

you should able be to call tostring on the datetime and the result will include all the parts down to the milliseconds.

Comment: Formatting the dates is the root of all evil.

Comment: Why mark this down? a better explanation of what's wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: In the OP I already state that I know how to add parameter. This is not the issue. The issue is precision on datetime parameters, and the baggage that goes with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the Type of the parameter either in the code behind file (like Karel suggested, specifying DateTime) or declarative by setting the Type property Type="DateTime"